# IndexOutOfBoundsException inside setStoppedState of WindowManagerGlobal

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, android-lifecycle, android-windowmanager

The top crash in our app only happens for Android 9, and only for a handful of devices, like ZTE, TCL, Hisense, BLU, HYUNDAI.

As we don't have access to any of these devices, we were not able to reproduce this, and as it occurs inside the Android framework, we are not sure it is an error in our code (though it must be, as we could not find any similar crashes in Stackoverflow).

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {MyActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
       at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4183)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4263)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:192)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6852)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

```
Caused by java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.setStoppedState(WindowManagerGlobal.java:604)
       at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:8831)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4205)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4183)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4263)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:192)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6852)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Anyone has experienced some similar crash, or has any idea of what the root cause may be?

Comment: Are you manually stopping the activity somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I am manually stopping the Activity in some places, e.g. when finishing the splash Activity which is shown every time the user opens the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [the code where the crash happens](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/d7785982ac7146896691e72ce48c82cf26dbb019:core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java;l=605;drc=7eec37989f1d030d8f933712e6cb2bff8d9e4104;bpv=1;bpt=0):

```
public void setStoppedState(IBinder token, boolean stopped) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        int count = mViews.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (token == null || mParams.get(i).token == token) {
                ViewRootImpl root = mRoots.get(i);
                root.setWindowStopped(stopped);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(the line numbers don't match your exception info exactly, because I didn't know the exact version of the code that your device uses.)

Assuming that we can expect `mViews`, `mParams`, and `mRoots` to be of the same length, this code looks correct.

However, if we move forward a bit in the git history, we find [commit 978e7f87](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/978e7f87cc0c1d2ff140694ec150c8eca10bfee6):

```
From: tetsutoki.shiozawa@sony.com
Subject: Fix: WindowManagerGlobal#setStoppedState failed by IOOBE

Symptom:
An application crashed due to IndexOutOfBoundsException.
The exception was thrown at WindowManagerGlobal#setStoppedState.

Root cause:
setStoppedState invokes setWindowStopped for each ViewRoot by
ascending order. If an application removes its view within the
loop, loop index exceeds the number of items.

Solution:
Loop in descending order.
```

I would assume that the devices where you're seeing the crash do not include this commit, while non-problematic devices do.

The new code looks like this:

```
public void setStoppedState(IBinder token, boolean stopped) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        int count = mViews.size();
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (token == null || mParams.get(i).token == token) {
                ViewRootImpl root = mRoots.get(i);
                // Client might remove the view by "stopped" event.
                root.setWindowStopped(stopped);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you can't affect the devices in question, you'll need to work around this problem. The commit message points us in a clear direction: make sure that you aren't removing views in the callbacks that are happening here.

Comment: Thank you for finding this info! We have tracked a few places where we are manually removing views, so we are going to try alternative approaches to check if we can solve this crash. I will update here in case we confirm that we were able to fix it.

Comment: Update: we found out that this was caused by a 3rd party library we were using, Pendo 1.x; after updating it to version 2.x, we've stopped seeing this crash.